# Provide a parametrization with the given properties: The curve is circled at point (a, b).

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Provide a parametrization with the given properties:

(a) The curve is circled at point (a, b). It is traced once counterclockwise, starting at the point (a+r, b) with $t \in [0, 2 \pi]$

(b) The line segment, connecting points in the direction from $(1,4,0)$ to $(6,7,-2)$

(c) The curve of intersection of the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and the ellipsoid $3x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2y$ in counterclockwise direction

---

attempt:

(a) $x = a + r cos(t), y = a+rsin(t)$ for $t \in [0, 2\pi]$

(b) $x = (1-t(1)) + 6(t) = 1 + 5t$, $y = (1-t)(4) + 7t = 4+3t, z = (1-t)(6) - 2(t) = 6-8t$

therefore $(1+5t, 4+3t, 6-8t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$

(c)

$3x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2y \to 4x^2+2y^2 = 2y \to 2x^2 + y^2 - y = 0$

$\to 2x^2 + y^2 - y + 1/4 - 1/4 = 0 \to 2x^2 + (y-1/2)^2 = 1/4 \to 8x^2 + 4(y-1/2)^2 = 1$

therefore $x = cos(t)\sqrt{8}$, $y = 1/2 + sin(t)/2$

hence, $(\sqrt{8}cos(t), 1/2 + 1/2 sin(t))$ for $0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a)
$y = b + \sin t,$ I think that was just a typo.

(b)
$z(0)$ should be $0$; you looked at $x(1)$ instead of $z(0).$

(c)
Since $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} > 0,$ we can say that the intersection of the two is given by
$$
\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{2y - y^2 - 3x^2} \implies 4x^2 +2(y^2-y) = 0
$$
We can rewrite this to form a perfect square as
$$
4x^2+2 \left( y - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 = \frac{1}{2} \implies \frac{x^2}{\left(8^{-1/2}\right)^2}+\frac{\left( y - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2}{\left(2^{-1}\right)^2} = 1,
$$
which is the equation of an ellipse centered at $(0,1/2)$. Thus we have the parameterization for $t \in (0, 2\pi)$ as
$$
\vec{r}(t) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle \frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{8}} \\
\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sin t}{2}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: You want to go from $(1,4,0)$ to $(6,7,-2)$. $z$ goes from $0$ to $-2$.